# How to calculate cumulative 90th percentile by period in ORACLE SQL

Tags: oracle, percentile

TASK: I want to calculate cumulative values of 90th percentile wait time in days to determine how long patients waited for their ultrasound scan by facility per  period and fiscal year (including total for all facilities).

HOW: I use over(partition by) expression to get the cumulative 90th percentile data in Oracle SQL.

ISSUE: receive an error (ORA-00979) "wait_time_days is not a GROUP BY expression" pointed out to the expression for cumulative 90th percentile -

Here is the simplified version of the query:

```
    define period_start = to_date ('20170401', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
    define period_end = to_date ('20180331', 'yyyy-mm-dd')   

            Select 
            to_char(add_months(c.PROCEDURE_PERFORMED_DT, -3),'YYYY') ||'/'|| to_char(add_months(c.PROCEDURE_PERFORMED_DT, 9),'YY') as Fiscal_year

            , nvl (CASE WHEN c.FACILITY_ID = 1 then 'OKANAGAN CLINIC'
                    WHEN c.FACILITY_ID = 2 THEN 'MELBOURNE CLINIC'
                    WHEN c.FACILITY_ID = 3 THEN 'VANCOUVER CLINIC'
                    WHEN c.FACILITY_ID = 4 THEN 'SHWARZ CLINIC'
                    WHEN c.FACILITY_ID = 5 THEN 'LADYSMITH CLINIC'
                    END, 'TOTAL') as FACILITY,
            , c.PROCEDURE_PERFORMED_DT
            , c.BOOKING_DT
            , round((c.PROCEDURE_PERFORMED_DT - c.BOOKING_FORM_RECEIVED_DT),2) as wait_time
            , p.period

        , round(percentile_cont(0.9) within group (order by wait_time asc),2) as Percentile_90th

        , percentile_cont(0.9) within group (order by wait_time asc)
     over(partition by CASE WHEN c.FACILITY_ID = 1 then 'OKANAGAN CLINIC'
                    WHEN c.FACILITY_ID = 2 THEN 'MELBOURNE CLINIC'
                    WHEN c.FACILITY_ID = 3 THEN 'VANCOUVER CLINIC'
                    WHEN c.FACILITY_ID = 4 THEN 'SHWARZ CLINIC'
                    WHEN c.FACILITY_ID = 5 THEN 'LADYSMITH CLINIC'
                    END) as Cumulative_Perc90th

    FROM COMPLETED_PROCEDURE c, PERIOD p   

     WHERE c.PROCEDURE_PERFORMED_DT between &period_start and &period_end
                   and c.PROCEDURE_PERFORMED_DT = p.END_DATE

                Group by 
                Fiscal_year
                , Rollup(CASE WHEN c.FACILITY_ID = 1 then 'OKANAGAN CLINIC'
                    WHEN c.FACILITY_ID = 2 THEN 'MELBOURNE CLINIC'
                    WHEN c.FACILITY_ID = 3 THEN 'VANCOUVER CLINIC'
                    WHEN c.FACILITY_ID = 4 THEN 'SHWARZ CLINIC'
                    WHEN c.FACILITY_ID = 5 THEN 'LADYSMITH CLINIC'
                    END)
                , period

Order By Facility, period
;
```

The PERIOD table (p) contains a list of some period dates as follows:

```
PERIOD   START_DATE     END_DATE

    01  2017-04-01  2017-04-20

    02  2017-04-21  2017-05-18

    03  2017-05-19  2017-06-15

    04  2017-06-16  2017-07-13
```

Thank you for your help!

P.S. I am using the same approach to calculate cumulative volumes (by summing all counted scans) and it works without any issues.

Comment: You have several column expressions with extra commas; you seem to be using the `facility` alias illegally in the `rollup()` (same level of query, as shown); and you *don't* have `wait_time_days` in your group-by clause so is this supposed to be demonstrating the first or second error? It is unclear, and simplifying the code seems to have caused distracting issues. [See MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: just my two cents -- I think you want to use some in-line views.  You are using aliases in your sql (like wait_time_days) -- but those aliases can't be referenced in other columns unless you wrap it all in an in-line view (or create a view) and use the alias in the outer sql

Comment: @AlexPoole: Thank you for your comment. I have edited the code and removed the extra commas. Also, I used the entire CASE statement for Facility in rollup. I would like to concentrate on solving the first error in regards having wait_time in my group-by clause. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what result you want to get from this query, but generally the error ORA-00979 appears because you're trying to use an analytic version of [PERCENTILE_CONT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions110.htm) which contains OVER(...) clause in aggregated GROUP BY query.

---

I try to show this issue using a simplified [example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0063ec/6), I hope this will help you understand what the error is and how this functions should be used.
 Let say we have the below table with 3 clinics and 10 records for each clinic:

```
CREATE TABLE example(
  clinic varchar2(100),
  wait_days_period int
);

INSERT ALL
INTO example VALUES('MELBOURNE CLINIC', x )
INTO example VALUES('VANCOUVER CLINIC', 10 + x )
INTO example VALUES('SHWARZ CLINIC', 10 * x )
SELECT level as X FROM dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10;
```

---

An aggregated version of the query looks like this - it contain PERCENTILE_CONT function **without OVER clause** used in **GROUP BY query**:

```
SELECT clinic,
       PERCENTILE_CONT(0.9) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY wait_days_period) as percen
FROM example
GROUP BY clinic;

|           CLINIC | PERCEN |
|------------------|--------|
| MELBOURNE CLINIC |    9.1 |
|    SHWARZ CLINIC |     91 |
| VANCOUVER CLINIC |   19.1 |
```

---

An analyticac version of the query looks like this -it contain PERCENTILE_CONT function **WITH OVER clause** used in **simple (not GROUP BY) query**:

```
SELECT clinic, wait_days_period,
       PERCENTILE_CONT(0.9) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY wait_days_period) 
       OVER (PARTITION BY clinic) as percen
FROM example  ORDER BY 1,2;

|           CLINIC | WAIT_DAYS_PERIOD | PERCEN |
|------------------|------------------|--------|
| MELBOURNE CLINIC |                1 |    9.1 |
| MELBOURNE CLINIC |                2 |    9.1 |
| MELBOURNE CLINIC |                3 |    9.1 |
| MELBOURNE CLINIC |                4 |    9.1 |
| MELBOURNE CLINIC |                5 |    9.1 |
| MELBOURNE CLINIC |                6 |    9.1 |
| MELBOURNE CLINIC |                7 |    9.1 |
| MELBOURNE CLINIC |                8 |    9.1 |
| MELBOURNE CLINIC |                9 |    9.1 |
| MELBOURNE CLINIC |               10 |    9.1 |
|    SHWARZ CLINIC |               10 |     91 |
|    SHWARZ CLINIC |               20 |     91 |
|    SHWARZ CLINIC |               30 |     91 |
|    SHWARZ CLINIC |               40 |     91 |
|    SHWARZ CLINIC |               50 |     91 |
|    SHWARZ CLINIC |               60 |     91 |
|    SHWARZ CLINIC |               70 |     91 |
|    SHWARZ CLINIC |               80 |     91 |
|    SHWARZ CLINIC |               90 |     91 |
|    SHWARZ CLINIC |              100 |     91 |
| VANCOUVER CLINIC |               11 |   19.1 |
| VANCOUVER CLINIC |               12 |   19.1 |
| VANCOUVER CLINIC |               13 |   19.1 |
| VANCOUVER CLINIC |               14 |   19.1 |
| VANCOUVER CLINIC |               15 |   19.1 |
| VANCOUVER CLINIC |               16 |   19.1 |
| VANCOUVER CLINIC |               17 |   19.1 |
| VANCOUVER CLINIC |               18 |   19.1 |
| VANCOUVER CLINIC |               19 |   19.1 |
| VANCOUVER CLINIC |               20 |   19.1 |
```

In short, the analytic version calculates exactly the same value as aggregated version (in GROUP BY query), but allows it to be used for each record in an ordinary query, without having to do additional GROUP BY subquery.

---

If you try to use the analytic version of the function (with OVER... clause) within the GROUP BY query, you will get `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression`, because this is not allowed:

```
SELECT clinic,
       PERCENTILE_CONT(0.9) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY wait_days_period) 
       OVER (PARTITION BY clinic) as percen
FROM example
GROUP BY clinic;

ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
```